# bootstrap, css, or responsive not working in mobile as well as pc

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

my website is constructed using PHP. If I visit on this page 
www.xyz.com/post.php
then this is work correctly in mobile as well as pc. If I visit on this page
www.xyz.com/post/23/what-is-php
then bootstrap not loading in both devices.

if I use the base href and meta viewport... something like this below

```
 <base href="http://localhost/postblog/post.php">
 <body style="background-color: #EAEAEA"> 



<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

then its work only in pc but not in mobile device...this is the problem
full head code

```
 <head>
<base href="http://localhost/postblog/post.php">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Blog Home - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="home/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="home/css/blog-home.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I use the httpaccess for frindly url...i think problem is arising for this

Comment: give the full header code

Comment: ok Mahfuzar Rahman

Answer (score 2):

remove `shrink-to-fit=no`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

add a slash to get content from home

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="/home/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="/home/css/blog-home.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

`shrink-to-fit=no` will just let any overflow fall off the screen. I would recommend trying without.